# noedynamic barcode on thermal printers are not scanned

Tags: zebra-printers, thermal-printer, barcode-printing, neodynamic

I am printing barcodes using neodynamic but there are issues in scanning on thermal printers while printing on laser printer, can scan easily. I have zebra printer TLP 2844. When code is like "G00001" then it scan but when code is like "G00001-ABC-ABC"  it is not scanned. Barcode settings are

```
barcode.Symbology = Symbology.Code128
barcode.BarWidth = 0.2
barcode.BarHeight = 5
barcode.TextAlignment = Alignment.AboveLeft
barcode.CodeAlignment = Alignment.BelowLeft
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that Neodynamic Barcode generates an image that gets printed. On the Zebra that image might be too low in resolution.

Do you only use the Neodynamic Barcode? If so, and under the premise that you need to use Neodynamic, then you need to get the Neodynamic ThermalLabel SDK, otherwise I'd recommend that you create the label layout in ZPL/EPL directly, then you can tell the printer directly to create a barcode of a specific symbology and content and it'll do the job just fine for you.